# Js logic in html,js, and css basic username and password script

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a basic username and password login using HTML, JS, and CSS. I've looked at a few examples for help and can't seem to find anything.

I'm very new at this stuff so it might not be perfect. here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="reee">
      <h1 id = "dad"> Login </h1>
    </div>
    <div class = "yes">
      <div id = "action">
        <form action="after sub/after.html">
      </div>
      <label class = "u" for="fname">Username</label>
      <input type="text" id="uname" name="user" placeholder="Your username...">
      <label class = "p" for="lname">Password</label>
      <input type="text" id="pass" name="pass" placeholder="Your password...">
      <script src = "script.js"></script>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" id = "loginto" onclick='reee()'><p class = "wrong" id = 
        "wrong"> </p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It seems a little chaotic and messy and I'm trying to work on that but that's not the point.

Here is the JS.

```
   function reee() {
    var user = document.getElementById("uname").value;
    var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
    var usernames = [
        ["johnsmith", "racH2sPu"],
        ["joe", "13579086"],
        ["donald", "KUzaDr@9"]
    ]
    var utest = usernames.some(function(uval) {
        return (usernames == user, pass);
    })
    if (utest != true) {
        document.getElementById("wrong").innerHTML = "Username or password incorrect"
        var wrong = true
        document.getElementById("action").innerHTML = "<form>"
    } else
        document.getElementById("action").innerHTML = "<form action='after sub/after.html'>"
}
```

Once again sorry if it is a little messy and chaotic I'm working on it.

I basically want to run through the array of usernames and passwords and make sure that it matches what the user put in the username and password boxes.

I also want to make sure that the username matches its password before continuing. If anyone knows how to get this to work pls let me know.

Comment: Very first thing - Javascript should not be used for login systems. If so, then only in the backend with nodejs. The thing you are trying to do may be a fancy school project, but should not be used in practice in real websites and applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do believe you are creating this for learning because, in the real world, there are a lot of security reasons to consider.

But you can create a login form using only HTML and JavaScript

It's kinda difficult to explain, please read the comment in this code below:

**NOTE: I've changed some of the `class`, and `id` name.**

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="reee">
      <h1 id = "dad"> Login </h1>
    </div>
 
      <div id = "action"> 
        <form>
          <label class ="u" for="fname">Username</label>
          <input type="text" id="uname" name="user" placeholder="Your username...">
          <label class = "p" for="lname">Password</label>
          <input type="text" id="pass" name="pass" placeholder="Your password...">
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" id = "loginto" onclick="reee()">
          <p class = "wrong" id = "status"></p> 
        </form>
    </div>
    
    <script src = "script.js"></script> // NOTE: ALways put the javascript file link in the bottom.
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var usernames = [ //This is the place to store usernames and passwords. In real world, you have to store it in database. In this case I store it in Javascript Object to improve readability
    {username: 'john', password: '123'},
    {username: 'albert', password: '234'},
    {username: 'tesla', password: '345'},
  ];

function reee() {
  var user = document.getElementById("uname").value; //Get user in put from form field
  var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < usernames.length; i++){ // Looping. To check every single data in usernames array above
    if(user != usernames[i].username || pass != usernames[i].password) { // Check if input is not equal to the usernames list
      document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "The password or username is incorrect"; //Display wrong message
    } else {
      document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Welcome " + user; //Display welcome message and username
      break; //To stop checking. Because username has already been found
    }
  }
}
```

I hope it will be helpful

**EDIT 1**: You can see the live demo [here](https://codepen.io/hisamafahri/pen/MWjaKdB)

**EDIT 2**: I've made a silly mistake. If we look at the code below:

```
/// ORIGINAL
if(user != usernames[i].username && pass != usernames[i].password) {
```

If we use that code we will pass the login page if the username OR the password is correct (not both), because I use the `&&`.

So, I have to use `||`, so the code should be:

```
// EDIT 2
if(user != usernames[i].username || pass != usernames[i].password) {
```

Now, the user should input the correct username and password in order to pass the login page.

I think everything should work fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing a huge fundamental issue here.

You really need a backend; look into NodeJS with Express if you like JavaScript.

There are so many things wrong with doing it like this.

1. User info is deleted upon reloading. Any user info created with this function is stored in the browser's RAM and is destroyed when the page is closed.
2. The existing user info (default info) can be accessed by anyone, even if they're not logged in.
3. Passwords are stored in plain text. This is so dangerous because if someone gets access to your database (which they can because it's front-end available) they will have your password. You NEED to hash it, and if you're not experienced with cybersecurity you should definitely use Firebase Google Authentication instead.
4. Input verification is done on the front-end. Of course, you don't have a back-end, but you want to do this on the back-end once you do some research into this. Otherwise, a user could directly fetch the backend from the console and bypass verification, thereby allowing SQL injection with zero effort.
5. Minor issue here. Your class names are not human-friendly to other developers or even future you. Please rename the input classes to something like "usernameBox," "passwordBox," and "loginErrorText."

There are a lot more I could list, but you really need to look into a tutorial on this because this is the most easily hackable code I've ever seen.